# Compare data of two or more maps

Tags: java, collections

I am stuck with the below requirement and not sure how can I proceed with it:

I have a function like:

```
public void compareExcel(Map<Object,List<HashMap>>) compareMaps){}
```

This function will take a map as an input parameter. This map will contain the sheet name vs Sheet values(Column name - column values) mapping.

Basically the function input parameters will be like:

```
<Excel1,(scenario:10)
        (timing: 20) 

Excel2,(scenario:30)
        (timing: 40) 

Excel3,(scenario:50)
        (timing: 60)
>
```

Here my excel1 having two columns(scenario and timings) and having values as 10 and 20 respectively.

In the result, I will be needing the comparison like:

Map>

```
<scenario, <excel1,10>
           <excel2,30>
           <excel3,50>

timing, <excel1,20>
           <excel2,40>
           <excel3,60>    
>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your code, or whatever it is, is very obscure. Try using words to explain your question.

Comment: That's not a comparison, that's a recopilation.

Comment: Did you tried something yourself?

Answer (score 1):

```
Create/initialize the details of you output data-structure

LOOP (over the excelName:List pairs in you input)
   LOOP (over the List that is the value in the pair)
      //Each entry in the list is a map
      Get the key-name (e.g. "scenario")
      Get the value (e.g. "10")
      //You already know the out key (i.e the excelName)
      With the three known values, build/add to your output data-structure
```

Answer (score 0):

On mobile so I can't even check syntax, but...

```
Map recopilation = new HashMap();
for(Object sheetName : compareMaps.keySet()) {
    Map sheet = compareMaps.get(sheetName);
    for (Object columnName : sheet.keySet()) {
        if (recopilation.get(columnName) == null) {
            recopilation.put(columnName, new HashMap());
        }
        ((Map) recopilation.get(columnName)).put(sheetName, sheet.get(columnName));
    }
}
```

Something like that. If it works, you should really throw some generics in there, I didn't mostly to save some typing.